# 12.04 Install Problem , Configuring Hardware

Tags: 12.04, hardware, configuration

Been trying different things for several hours now, the install comes to a halt when I reach the configuring hardware part of the installation.

have nvidia gtx580 and asus rog maxius gene-z. did have gpu hangup when i instaled without disabling the feature in f6 like I read on the net.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Just after you BIOS finishes displaying its stuff, press shift a few times to make the GRUB menu appear.  Choose Ubuntu advanced options and choose to boot in safe graphics mode.

You should be able to do the install.  After the install if you still have problems (like I did) the do this.

Boot in safe graphics mode again, but this time from the HDD and not the Disk, and log in.  If this doesn't work you can try hit ctl-alt-F1 and log in via the command prompt.

Once in the safe graphics mode open up a terminal by pressing ctl-alt-T [not necassary if you did the ctl-alt-F1 step]

Type these command in one by one.

```
    sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
    sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
    sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
    sudo update-alternatives --config gl_conf
    sudo ldconfig
    sudo update-initramfs -u
    sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

Reboot.  This worked for me.

Good luck